# How can I embed my navigation controller into my tab bar controller programmatically in Swift Xcode 8.2?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, model-view-controller, uitabbarcontroller

I have been teaching my self how to develop and I got to the point to where I need guidance from experts. I created some of the user interface programmatically using the MVC structure. My question is how can I embed my navigation controller into my tab bar controller so my tab bar controller can be on every screen.  I made the tab bar controller in main.storyboard and referenced it in the View controller I named Home Controller.

```
    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let tabViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBar")

    self.present(tabViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The code above is in the view did load function. I was wondering do I need to change up the root view controller in my app delegates?

```
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()      
    window?.rootViewController =  UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeController(collectionViewLayout: layout))
```

This is in my finished launched func.

Answer (score 0):

Use following lines

```
var navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController));

tabBarController.viewControllers = [navigationController,firstViewControllersecondViewController, ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. But would I put that in my delegates file or my view controller? Also do I need to delete the like that already sets the root view controller in the delegates?

Comment: View controller where you have created tabBarController

Comment: Ok. I Used the following lines in my View controller but i get the error unresolved identifier for viewController and firstViewControllersecondViewController. Sorry if I'm just being dumb but do I need to change those to something else? thanks for your time

Comment: Yes its just an example you can remove both if you dont have any other controller that need to be attached with tabbarcontroller

Comment: Sorry again and thanks for your time. But this is what i have.

Comment: let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController:       tabViewController );
        
  tabBarController?.viewControllers = [navigationController, ]

Comment: my tab bar screen is showing over my navigation controller in the simulator. And I'm trying to get it to show with my navigation controller until one of the tabs is clicked if that makes since.

Comment: Also I set window = to UIWindow and the later set window as my root view controller in the delegates. Do I need to change that?

Answer (score 0):

create a separate UITabBarController class and initialize it in AppDelegate like this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
      window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

      window?.rootViewController = MyTabBarController()

      window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

      return true
}
```

and the custom tabBarController

```
import UIKit

class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
        self.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        self.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.4)

        let firstViewController = FirstViewController()

        let firstViewTabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "First", image: UIImage(named: "calculator"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "calculator"))

        firstViewController.tabBarItem = firstViewTabBarItem
        firstViewController.tabBarItem.tag = 0

        let historyViewController = HistoricDataViewController()

        historyViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .history, tag: 1)

        let tabBarList = [calculateViewController, historyViewController]

        viewControllers = tabBarList.map{UINavigationController(rootViewController: $0)}

    }

}
```

Hope this example helps.